# AmazonS3Exception Bad Request: distcp from frankfurt s3 to emr hdfs failing

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

I am trying to copy a file from a s3 bucket from Frankfurt (eu-central-1) onto my hdfs hosted via EMR in Ireland (eu-west-1). The copy commands I tried to execute where:

```
hdfs dfs -cp "s3a://<bucket>/<file>" /user/hadoop/<file>
```

and

```
s3-dist-cp --src "s3a://<bucket>/" --dest hdfs:///user/hadoop/ --srcPattern <file>
```

and

```
hadoop distcp "s3a://<bucket>/<file>" /user/hadoop/<file>
```

In all cases (and various permutations regarding extra options and s3, s3a, s3n on all of those commands) I do get something like the following exception:

```
16/01/15 11:48:24 ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 4A77158C1BD71C29), S3 Extended Request ID:     LU41MspxqVnHqyaMreTvggRG480Wb9d+TBx1MAo5v/g9yz07mmPizcZVOtRMQ+GElXs8vl/WZXA=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:803)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:505)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3595)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1041)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1013)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.GlobbedCopyListing.doBuildListing(GlobbedCopyListing.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createInputFileListing(DistCp.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:401)
```

So I figured using s3a uses amazon's sdk behind the scenes. After a lot of research I found the presumed cause:

Link: [Amazon s3a returns 400 Bad Request with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209196/amazon-s3a-returns-400-bad-request-with-spark)

Link: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/360

So in summary Frankfurt and some other other newer centers are 'only' capable of using Signature Version 4, but all of the commands hadoop cp, distcp or s3-dist-cp can do is use Version 2?

Since using s3a is using the aws sdk, I tried to enforce the use of Signature V4 by adding

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4 -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enforceV4"
```

But to no avail.

This fact made me try doing all the above but with a bucket **NOT** in eu-central-1 but e.g. on eu-west-1. That worked. So I guess this is it?

Is there a solution to this problem? Anyone experiencing this too?

**EDIT**

A working alternative is to use aws cli to download the data from s3 onto the master and then use, e.g.

```
hdfs dfs -put <src> <dst>
```

to get the job done. But what to do if this is really massive data not fitting on the master node?

Comment: Have you tried Hive, create external table with this S3 data and load it directly to hdfs?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I will definitely try (and give feedback). What are your thoughts on why this information could help understand the situation further?

Comment: @CarstenBlank Did you figure out how to solve or workaround this issue?

Comment: @rontron No I haven't. I, however, have abandoned EMR altogether as I can pull up a hadoop cluster much faster to my likings with only those dependencies/applications I really need using EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get data from s3, FRA into HDFS by specifying the endpoint:

```
hdfs dfs -Dfs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId=<access key ID> -Dfs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey=<secret acces key> -Dfs.s3a.endpoint=<s3 enpoint> -ls s3a://<bucket_name>/...
```

You do not and should not copy it locally.

Answer (score 0):

S3a supports frankfurt & seol; it's something we explicitly test against. As lulia notes, you do need to set the endpoint. The [hadoop docs for s3a](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/index.md) cover this.

Note that once you fix the endpoint to be frankfurt or seol, you can no longer access data in other regions, as they don't relay to them.