# AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request 400 when trying to use S3AFilesystem

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have java code which tries to initialize a remote filesystem from S3 using coniguration (this was previously on HDFS and I try to move this to s3 without modifying the code too much).

This is the config:

```
fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
fs.defaultFS=s3a://mybucket.devrun.algo-resources/
```

Then, in the setup I use

```
hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

This results in the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException: doesBucketExist on mybucket.devrun.algo-resources: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 1E91F85FA3751C44), S3 Extended Request ID: 5KDgH7lsaIX7l5DQcdBdUjeg/qxYgOEU4WJBOL0p090kqNNlYOAie31zuYUQw+R3LN4CvavdVJk=: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 1E91F85FA3751C44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:181)
    at pipeline.HdfsSyncUtils.<init>(HdfsSyncUtils.java:32)
    at pipeline.QueriesForArticles$QFAMapper.setup(QueriesForArticles.java:158)
    at AWSPipeline.C2SIndexSearchingAlgo.<init>(C2SIndexSearchingAlgo.java:41)
    at AWSPipeline.ABTestMainRunner.main(ABTestMainRunner.java:27)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 1E91F85FA3751C44), S3 Extended Request ID: 5KDgH7lsaIX7l5DQcdBdUjeg/qxYgOEU4WJBOL0p090kqNNlYOAie31zuYUQw+R3LN4CvavdVJk=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1107)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:276)
    ... 11 more
```

I use `hadoop-aws.jar` version `2.8.0`

I use `awsfed` to create a credentials file under `~\.aws`, so I think I have my credentials right.

Any idea what is the meaning of this error? There's no detailed error message...

**Edit:**

For anyone interested, I solved this:
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209196/amazon-s3a-returns-400-bad-request-with-spark), I came to the conclusion that this is region-related. My bucket is on us-east-2 region. I tried opening a bucket in another region and it worked!

This is probably related to what can be [seen in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) - S3 in us-east-2 supports only version 4 signing, and my code (`hadoop-aws.jar 2.8.0`) probably uses an older version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent hours in debugging where my bukcet was in us-east-2 region. Recreated bucket in another region and worked like a charm!!