# Can't connect from Spark to S3 - AmazonS3Exception Status Code: 400

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect from Spark (running on my PC) to my S3 bucket:

```
 val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("S3Client")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext;
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY)
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY)
    val txtFile = sc.textFile("s3a://bucket-name/folder/file.txt")
    val contents = txtFile.collect();
```

But getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400,
>   AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 07A7BDC9135BCC84, AWS Error
>   Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID:
>   6ly2vhZ2mAJdQl5UZ/QUdilFFN1hKhRzirw6h441oosGz+PLIvLW2fXsZ9xmd8cuBrNHCdh8UPE=

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209196/amazon-s3a-returns-400-bad-request-with-spark) but it didn't help me.

**Edit:**

As Zack suggested, I added:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
```

But I still get the same exception.

Comment: Could you try adding `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl "  ,   "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solve the problem.

I was targeting a region (Frankfurt) that required using version 4 of the signature.

I've changed the region of the S3 bucket to Ireland and now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

According to [s3 doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region), some region only support "Signature Version(s) 4", need to add the configurations below:

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true"
```

and

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alon,

try the below configurations:

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("S3Client")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext;
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY)
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY)
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
    val txtFile = sc.textFile("s3a://s3a://bucket-name/folder/file.txt")
    val contents = txtFile.collect();
```

I believe your issue was due to you not specifying your endpoint in the configuration set. Sub out `us-east-1` for whichever region you use.

Comment: I've added the endpoint (in my case the region is eu-central-1), but I still get the same exception

Comment: @Alon - Did you resolved the issue? can you provide the solution

Comment: @LearnHadoop Yes I have, You can see my accepted answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (this is everything...no other export etc. is needed)

```
    sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_KEY)
    sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET)
    sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
```

to run:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4' --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4'   --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1  spark_read_s3.py
```